# vectorized atomic add in single thread

Tags: cuda, vectorization, atomic

The SM is capable of performing [multiple atomics ops per cycle](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3101-Atomic-Memory-Operations.pdf#page=28). This ability can be utilized by having threads in a warp perform atomic ops on adjacent memory locations.

Is it possible to perform several atomic ops in a single cycle from a single thread?

```
atomicAdd(addr + 0, val1);
atomicAdd(addr + 1, val2);
atomicAdd(addr + 2, val3);
atomicAdd(addr + 3, val4);
```

The above code is executed as four separate atomic operations instead of being coalesced into one vector atomic operation.

<s>If it wasn't atomic, it would be possible using the vector data types.</s>

```
float4 vec;
vec = *addr; // single load
vec.x += val1;
vec.y += val2;
vec.z += val3;
vec.w += val4;
*addr = vec; // single store
```

For some reason, `atomicAdd` isn't overloaded for the vector types even though it feels like it's possible (well, if different threads in a warp can achieve it, why can't a single thread?).

Comment: No it is not... (and I don't understand your second code, there is no way that would happen in one cycle irrespective of whether the memory transactions are atomic or not)

Comment: Is there any technical reason why it isn't supported? If the hardware can coalesce atomic add from different threads, why can't there be an instruction to do it from the same thread? (just like the normal vector types)

Comment: @talonmies Oops! Yes, the second code doesn't happen in a single cycle. That was a bad example.

Comment: No it was a canonical example, precisely because (with a couple of exceptions for 8 bit types), there are no instructions to perform wide vector arithmetic at a thread level. If there are no instructions for the non-atomic case, why is it illogical there are no atomic operations of that character either?.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to perform several atomic operations from the same thread in the same "cycle" for the same reason it isn't possible to the same with normal additions, memory writes etc.. from a single thread. There isn't an instruction for it (at least in PTX). It wouldn't make sense any way, it would have to use a completely separate mechanism than coalesced atomics.

Coalesced atomics work because you have all threads in a warp writing to similar location, similar to normal coalesced memory operations.  Since non divergent threads execute the same instruction, it makes it easier for some scheduling mechanism to group these memory writes (which don't have to be synchronous with said threads).

What you are talking about is a different mechanism, one that either requires some hardware to arbitrarily look ahead to figure out writes for all threads in a warp, or a *single* instruction that encapsulates multiple writes, and this just doesn't make sense for atomics to have some special privilege here.

Comment: The series of atomic operations in my example access to consecutive locations. The SM can coalesce 32bit regular loads from several threads into one big load. A similar effect can be achieved using vector data types to perform a 64/128 bit load in a single thread. I thought it was reasonable to speculate the possibility to perform a vector atomic ops as the SM could coalesce from different threads.

Comment: There are no vector atomic ops.  The maximum size of any atomic operation on a GPU is 64-bits.  Multiple 64-bit locations cannot be combined in any way.